# Git push The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, git-push

Buen día, mi problema es que quiero subir cambios a mi repositorio remoto pero en la Git Bash no me permite lanzandome el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Con la aplicacion de GitHub Desktop me permite subir cambios de manera normal pero en la Git Bash no me permite.

Ya he estado investigando un poco y al parecer cambie de usuario debido a que abri con visual studio el repositorio local haciendo por automatico un cambio de usuario como se muestra en la imagen dice Austin1400.

Ya cambie mi user.name y user.email ha como estaba antes, use -f para forzar el push obviamente, pero no he podido arreglar este problema.

Lo que tengo entendido es que tengo que cambiar de cuenta de manera que tengo que autenticar mi usuario y contraseña como al inicio, ya que solo se me solicito la primera vez que me logee en git de ahi en adelante cada push que hago no me solicita autenticarme y se sube los cambios a mi repositorio remoto.

Si alguien sabe como habilitar alguna configuración para solicitar la autenticacion cada vez que se haga push se lo agradeceria, u otra opcion es modificar algun archivo colocando el usser y password aunque creo que esta opcion no es tan valida ya que la cuenta supongo que se valida con una conexion a internet para hacer consultas de que exista dicho usuario.

Comment: Revisa tu fichero `~/.gitconfig` a ver si tienes alguna configuración sobre las credenciales que debas borrar. Puedes editar ese fichero con cualquier editor de texto y eliminar (o si prefieres comentar) lo que no proceda.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia

Esta es la configuracion de mi fichero git config, sinceramente no se que pudiera ser lo que no proceda :(

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/theLastPixel/Home-sales-web.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "pageNosotros"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/pageNosotros

Comment: Parece que el gitconfig que muestras es el que hay dentro del repositorio. Yo me refería al gitconfig "global" el que está en tu carpeta "Home" (la primera en que apareces al abrir git bash, a la que puedes regresar poniendo `cd` sin argumentos). Ese `.gitconfig` será el que contenga tu nombre de usuario y seguramente también la configuración de "helper" de credenciales que está recordando tu contraseña.

Comment: Ya revise el contenido del archivo gitconfig

[http]
        sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
        sslBackend = openssl
        [diff "astextplain"]
        textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
 clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
 smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
 process = git-lfs filter-process
 required = true
[credential]
 helper = manager

Comment: Prueba a quitar la sección `[credential]` (haz una copia antes por si acaso)

Comment: Listo pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. (Ya lo regrese originalmente)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problema **RESUELTO**

Dentro de la carpeta oculta de mi repositorio local .git abri el archivo config (el cual se puede abrir con un editor de código o con la misma git bash como los pros :D )

Donde por defecto te saldrá algo así

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/theLastPixel/Home-sales-web.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "pageNosotros"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/pageNosotros
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

Revise un poco de la documentacion de Git respecto a credenciales en el siguiente link https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Almacenamiento-de-credenciales

Y por ultimo revise un video en youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGw1lvcv75U&t=286s respecto a múltiples usuarios en git y como solicitar siempre la clave hacia el repositorio remoto ya que por defecto en las ultimas versiones no solamente es posible solicitar la clave por primera vez a la conexión remota con **SSH** si no también por **HTTPS** lo cual hace lo mismo (Solicitar solo una vez la clave posteriormente los push que realices no te solicitara credenciales para la autentican de la cuenta RECALCANDO que ya te lo solicito la primera vez).

podemos observar en la siguiente imagen que por defecto solicitar las credenciales esta en auto segun la documentacion de GIT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por lo que debemos agregar o cambiar esta opción ya sea que lo quieras hacer en --local o en --global o en --system al archivo .gitconfig [credential]
    interactive = always

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/theLastPixel/Home-sales-web.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "pageNosotros"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/pageNosotros
[credential]
    interactive = always
```

En mi caso yo desinstale git antes de hacer esta configuracion, pero no era necesario supongo espero ayude esta solución ***EXITO.***

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución agregar un SSH
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh

ya agregado el SSH, cambiar la URL

git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/{nombre}/{repo}.git

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Error: The requested URL returned error: 403 While pushing to a GitHub repository](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jysf-_kH0AM) Hola seguí los pasos de este video y en mi caso desde una pc con windows 10, borré las credenciales relacionadas con github; luego vscode me pidió autorizar en github y funcionó. Espero y les ayude.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/339954)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la recomendación.
Bueno en resumidas cuentas, solo tuve que borrar las credenciales de windows relacionadas con github; de esa forma cuando volví a enviar los cambios al github, visual studio code me pidió loguearme de nuevo y eso fue todo en mi caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve ese problema al estar trabajando una vez en una PC ajena. Lo único que tuve que hacer aparte de cambiar el email y el user name en el config fue correr el comando

```
git config --local credential.helper ""
```

para así poner el default y borrar las credenciales del anterior usuario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS extension in VS Code, you can see in this explorer extension your logs. In my case, the log I got

```
[ERROR]: _aws.auth.reauthenticate: Error: Unable to authenticate connection
         -> SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20221230T155746Z is now earlier than 20221230T160514Z (20221230T162014Z - 15 min.) (statusCode: 403; requestId: 3bdab4d0-0cfc-4050-baf0-8d508cc4707c)
```

Another question in stackoverflow gave me this answer that may possible help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017410/signature-expired-is-now-earlier-than-error-invalidsignatureexception

Synchronize your machines local clock with NTP:

sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org

Comment: Saludos, el idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu respuesta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A mi no me funciono con ninguna de las respuestas anteriores, asi que probe con ssh y dió en el clavo, recomiendo este video: https://youtu.be/g0ZV-neSM7E